# Parameterize C for $\int_C \pi exp(\pi \bar{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is "$f(z) = \pi exp(\pi \bar{z})$ and C is the boundary of the square with vertices at the points 0, 1, 1+i, and i, the orientation of C being the counterclockwise direction." I have the picture drawn and know that $C = C_1 +C_2 + C_3 + C_4$ and know how to solve the problem once I have C parameterized. I just do not understand how to parameterize C. Hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you'll have to make a piecewise parametrization, one for each side of the square.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yes I know that like I know each $C_i$ has to be parameterize separately I just dont understand how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could split the parametrization into 4 parts - and integrate each. A curve from $z_1$ to $z_2$ could be parameterized by $$ \gamma(t) = z_2 t+(1-t)z_1, \quad t\in[0,1].$$

Comment: Yes and Ive seen that already but how do you get that is my question. Like how do you know that $\gamma(t)$ is equal to that.

Comment: It doesn't have to be - there are infinitely many such parametrization. But this is the simplest (aka linear). Thus it needs to be of the form $\gamma(t) = a+bt$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$. Now since $\gamma(0)=z_1$ and $\gamma(1)=z_2$ you may solve and find that $a=z_1$ and $b=z_2-z_1$ - writing that a little different gives my parametrization.

Comment: ahhh my book tried to explain but your explanation is much better! thank you!